# Laravel: Textbox value is not getting received

Tags: laravel

View file:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <input type="checkbox" name="img_check" id="upload" value="dummy value">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
```

Controller file:

```
function editProduct(Request $request){
  echo 'Checkbox value: '.$request->input('img_check');
  ............
  ............
  ............

  return view('dashboard.editProduct', array('product' => $productData,                                                
                                                'categories' => $categoriesData,
                                                'shippingPolicy' => $shippingPolicyData,
                                                'returnPolicy' => $returnPolicyData,
                                            'subcategory' => $subcategory,
                                            'success' => $success));`
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Checkbox value:
```

Output shows only text message, not textbox value.

All other fields of forms are working fine but only checkbox value is not getting received.

Surprisingly it is working fine on other form of mine which is being called from another controller. I tried a lot but couldn't figure out what is making textbox value fail!

Any idea?

EDIT:

Route path:

```
 Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'edit_product', [dashboardController:: class, 'editProduct']);
```

Comment: You need to add the action in the form tag.

Comment: @dev Empty action mean, current page url. All other fields are working fine in same form. I think issue is only with checkbox.

Comment: @Rishabh.you have to click checkbox or else it return empty

Comment: @johnlobo Yes, I did click checkbox. No luck.

Comment: can you show route for that request because action is empty so its going to same route but youe method code doesnt show return view for that blade and als no crsf token in form

Comment: @johnlobo I have updated answer with route path. I also added `@csrf` in form. I am not showing full form data coz my form contains many fields. Post might get lengthy coz of it

Comment: @Rishabh but where is method of returning form view

Comment: @johnlobo Updated question with view method. All other fields are working fine. So calling method or route can't be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is extremely strange behaviors of laravel 8.**

What actually I did was, I copy checkbox field from other form of my project and paste it in current form (in which I was doing modifications). So simply copied one field from another form to my current form.

And laravel wasn't accepting this copy paste field as input field. It's value wasn't getting received and it wasn't entering in following if condition `if($request->isMethod('POST')){`   .

> So finally I typed checkbox checkbox field by myself and that field started to work!!!!

I mean why..............!!?? If I copy paste any field from one page to another then laravel don't consider it as input field but if you typed then it started working!!

Here is my previous textbox field

```
<input type="checkbox" name="img_check" id="upload" value="dummy value">
```

And here it is my new checkbox field which I typed instead of copy paste

```
<input type="checkbox" name="allow" id="upload" value="hello">
```

And new checkbox was working. Damn I am so confused.... whats the difference between those fields?? IS this laravel's some kind of bug or what...?

> NOTE: Both forms ware already being made and working. For little modifications I did copy one field from one to another form. On newly created form, copy paste field didn't bother me.

Answer (score 0):

your method should check whether `request` is `post` or `get`.So in `request get` method it return empty

```
public function editProduct(Request $request){

  if($request->isMethod('POST')){
    dd($request->input('img_check'));
  }

   return view('dashboard.editProduct', array('product' => $productData,                                                
                                            'categories' => $categoriesData,
                                            'shippingPolicy' => $shippingPolicyData,
                                            'returnPolicy' => $returnPolicyData,
                                        'subcategory' => $subcategory,
                                        'success' => $success));`
 
}
```

Comment: Strange, using `dd()` I can see value of checkbox. But why not with `echo`? What I was actually tring to use checkbox in `if` condition. But `if` condition was never getting true, thats why I tried to `echo` checkbox to check if checkbox getting value or not. But neither I was able to print checkbox value nor `if` condition did work :(

Comment: @Rishabh its not issue of echo you have use request is method post .and also return inside if condition of post or else it goes to view

Comment: I am new in laravel. So you saying my checkbox is not considered as `post` method like my other fields? This is what It seems. Besides how would I make `if` condition for checkbox to check if it is checked or have some values?

Comment: This is what I tried `if($request->has('img_check')){  ` and `if(!empty($request->input('img_check')))`

Comment: @Rishabh.better always check if($request->isMethod('POST')){ then inside of that method you can check thse methods

Comment: Yes, I am already using `if($request->isMethod('POST')){ ` That's why my update form is successfully updating every data except checkbox. Only checkbox somehow is not working.

Comment: use if(!empty($request->img_check)) or  check if($request->has('img_check'))

Comment: Hey buddy, After doing some testing and hopeless editing, I finally accidently solved my issue. Please check my answer and see if you know anything about it. Because I am still unable to understand how it worked this way.

Comment: @Rishabh.try clearing view cache by running php artsain view:clear and php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

Update your route path to **post** as suggested by John.
If you are doing update operation it will be post method, get is only used for fetching the data.

```php
 Route::match(['post'], 'edit_product', [dashboardController:: class, 'editProduct']);
```

Comment: I got your point. But question here is, How my other fields (textbox, select) are working fine with same route. Only checkbox is getting issue. Why?

Comment: @Rishabh Try checked for input field to see if that works with the whole form  `<input type="checkbox" name="img_check" id="upload" value="dummy value" checked>`

Comment: Hey buddy, After doing some testing and hopeless editing, I finally accidently solved my issue. Please check my answer and see if you know anything about it. Because I am still unable to understand how it worked this way.